# Certify origin of downloaded file

Tags: web

Assume I visit the following link `somerandomwebsite.com/a.pdf` and download the file `a.pdf`. Now assume that the host replaces `a.pdf` with a new version of the same file under the same name so now the previous link would lead me to download a different file.

Is there a way for me to prove that the file I downloaded was indeed downloaded from that link at a given time?

Comment: Is this a programming question or a general computer usage question? If it's not programming-specific it would be better posted on [Super User](https://superuser.com) or perhaps [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/). If it is about programming then please tag the language you're using and tell us more about the program you're writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## File Attribute

This is by no means a proof you can use to convince someone else, but if your browser, platform, and file system support it, you may find an `xattr` on the downloaded file that tells you the URL.

On macOS:

```
$ xattr -l -p com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms Downloads/logo-stackoverflow.svg 
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 A1 01 5F 10 47 68 74 74  |bplist00.._.Ghtt|
00000010  70 73 3A 2F 2F 73 74 61 63 6B 6F 76 65 72 66 6C  |ps://stackoverfl|
00000020  6F 77 2E 64 65 73 69 67 6E 2F 61 73 73 65 74 73  |ow.design/assets|
00000030  2F 69 6D 67 2F 6C 6F 67 6F 73 2F 73 6F 2F 6C 6F  |/img/logos/so/lo|
00000040  67 6F 2D 73 74 61 63 6B 6F 76 65 72 66 6C 6F 77  |go-stackoverflow|
00000050  2E 73 76 67 08 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00  |.svg............|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 54                                |.....T|
00000076
```

On Linux:

```
$ getfattr -d logo-stackoverflow.svg 
# file: logo-stackoverflow.svg
user.xdg.origin.url="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg"
```

## Wayback Machine

You might find the URL was archived by a service, such as [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org). For example: https://web.archive.org/web/20201101014003/https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg

## Timestamping Authority (TSA)

For a convincing proof, you might rely on a third-party to access the URL and provide a cryptographic signature with the contents, including a timestamp. For example: [freetsa.org](https://www.freetsa.org/index_en.php#url) provides a "URL screenshot online" service you can use to get a signed PDF showing the accessed website.